# Java cannot find method symbol

Tags: java, javafx, lombok

I am trying to access a method from inside the connectEvent method in Controller.java and it gives me the error:

```
Java: cannot find symbol
symbol: method getConnection()
location: variable main of type sample.Main
```

Have I overlooked something?
I have tried everything
Cheers

Controller.java

```
    package sample;

import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class Controller{

    @Getter
    private Main main;

    public Controller(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    //FXML to Java Links

    @FXML
    @Getter
    private Button connectButton;

    @FXML
    @Getter
    private TextArea passwordText;

    @FXML
    @Getter
    private TextArea ipText;

    @FXML
    @Getter
    private TextArea usernameText;


    //FXML linked methods

    /**
     * Called when user tries to connect using supplied information
     */

    @FXML
    public void connectEvent(ActionEvent event){
        main.getConnection().connect(getUsernameText().getText(), passwordText.getText(), ipText.getText());
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import lombok.Getter;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Getter
    private Controller controller;

    @Getter
    private Connection connection = new Connection();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Startup.fxml"));
        controller = loader.getController();

        Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("Startup.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("MCManager");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 850, 600));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Connection

```
package sample;

public class Connection {

    public void connect(String username, String password, String ip){

    }

}
```

Comment: According to the Lombok documentation: "The [lombok] jar file will still need to be included in the classpath of any projects that will use Project Lombok annotations.".  Is the lombok jar on your classpath?  If it is and you are still having issues, remove all the lombok imports and annotations from your code and ensure it works OK without lombok before adding lombok annotations back in gradually (if you still want to use them).

Comment: It is there, I did try without lombok and it does work.

Comment: What versions of Lombok and java are you using? How do you compile? Do you use Eclipse and do you compile with javac (via maven, ant) or ecj?

Comment: Lombok version is the latest one. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, and javac

Answer (score 5):

In you controller you are calling `main.getConnection()`

```
@FXML
public void connectEvent(ActionEvent event){
    main.getConnection().connect(getUsernameText().getText(), passwordText.getText(), ipText.getText());
}
```

But in your Main Class there is no `getConnection()` method.

Put following code in your Main class.

```
public Connection  getConnection(){
 return connection;
}
```

Comment: Wait no, not solved. The @Getter creates a getConnection() method. Its apart of the lombok lib.